# Replacing an alphanumerical text from a url with a combination of aplha numerical text from the same url

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, excel-formula, python-requests

I am stuck with a unique situation where I need to replace an alphanumerical text in an url with a combination of another text in the same url

Here is an example url

web_url("ABC_584","URL=https://ABCD.com/dEKgZETqwmDAh1rP/ArcGIS/rest/services/Overlay_Character/FeatureServer/0/query?

in this url I need to replace "ABC_584" with "Overlay_Character_0"

"ABC_584" is not static and that changes, so anything in the quote after web_url("XYZ_0-9" (i.e XYZ_0-9 in this case), has to be replaced by text after "Service/" and the number after FeatureServer/ from the above url

One more thing "ABC_584" can also be "123_123" completely numerical!

There are 100's of URL which I need to do it for and thus manually not possible, I tried VB script, writing Excel formulas to no use

Anyone here who can help me with this using any of the approach possible via Excel or Python code?

Thanks for reading, do let me know if you need more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do can be done in gvim (or vi, vim) editor by a one line regex-replace command (one line for all URLs):

```
:%s/web_url(".*","\(.*services\/\(.*\)\/FeatureServer\/\(.*\)\/query\)\@=/web_url("\2_\3","/g
```

A similar regex can also be done using Python (loop through all your URLs).

```
import re
print (re.sub("web_url\(\"(.*)\",\"(?=.*services\/(.*)\/FeatureServer\/(.*)\/query)",r'web_url("\2_\3","', [your url string]))
```

If you really want to use Excel formula:

1. extract the "ABC_584" by `=mid([url], 10, find(""",""",[url])-10)`
2. extract the group after "services/" by `=LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID([url],FIND("services/", [url])+LEN("services/"),1000),"/FeatureServer/","_"), LEN(SUBSTITUTE(MID([url],FIND("services/", [url])+LEN("services/"),1000),"/FeatureServer/","_"))-LEN("/query?"))`
3. Replace (1) with (2) using Excel formula by `=SUBSTITUTE([url], [1], [2])`

Comment: The VIM Re-ex Expression worked great for me I used it but was missing on escape sequence, definately gave a baseline for other URL Pattern!. I used it with VIM editor!

If someone needs a download link, here it is :- https://vim.en.softonic.com

Comment: Here are the steps I performend:

once you download 
 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim82
 
Start: - gvim.exe - Application
 
It will open a text editor
 
Copy your URLS and the paste it in the Editor:- The Normal Copy paste might not work when writing the Regex function at the bottom
 
So go to edit option and use paste from there

Also to write the Regular Expression you need to press : colan and it will take you to the bottom line

and then you can paste the regular expression provided in the solution By Oliver

Comment: :%s/web_url(".*","\(.*services\/\(.*\)\/FeatureServer\/\(.*\)\/query\)\@=/web_url("\2_\3","/g

Don't forget to use the Colen before %s

I will also explore the other solutions you provided using Python and Excel and try to add comments

Comment: Thanks @PankajHarde, just added the ":" to the Vi solution

Comment: Forgot to Thank you Oliver ! Thanks @Oliver Leung